# passing get request for web api in httprequest in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using cloud currency Web API for fetching values using get method. I am getting error of The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Please guide me to solve it.

```
string url = "https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed"+"?buy_currency="+buy+"&sell_currency="+sell+"&fixed_side="+fix+"&amount="+amount;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";

string auth_token = TempData["response"].ToString();

request.Headers["auth_token"] = auth_token;
request.ContentType = "application/json;";

string responseText = String.Empty;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
string response = responseText;
```

Comment: Pretty clear: you need to authorize your call.

Comment: @CodeCaster  I am passing valid auth_token which i am generating along with all the necessary parameters. You can have a look at this link.

Comment: https://connect.currencycloud.com/documentation/api-docs/get-rates-detailed

Comment: The response you get does not agree with that.

Comment: @CodeCaster Is there some mistake in the way i am passing header request? I suppose i am not sending authentication token in proper way or it is not getting added to header..I am working on that though!!

Comment: @CodeCaster I am having another issue with post request. Can you have a look at it and suggest possible solution..Thank you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497430/using-httppost-method-for-webapi.  Here is the documentation for that.   https://connect.currencycloud.com/documentation/api-docs/post-conversions-create

Comment: The format used by currency cloud is as follows for creating a conversion.curl -X POST -d "buy_currency=EUR&sell_currency=GBP&fixed_side=sell&amount=1500&reason=testing&term_agreement=true" --header "X-Auth-Token: XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX" https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/conversions/create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding the token properly. According to [their documentation](https://connect.currencycloud.com/documentation/getting-started/cookbook), the header name is `X-Auth-Token`, not `auth_token` as you use.

So change:

```
request.Headers["auth_token"] = auth_token;
```

To:

```
request.Headers["X-Auth-Token"] = auth_token;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Got it working...appreciate your help :-)